# How to combine 5 tables together with same ID in a query?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have 5 different tables T_DONOR, T_RECIPIENT_1, T_RECIPIENT_2, T_RECIPIENT_3, and T_RECIPIENT_4. All 5 tables have the same CONTACT_ID.

This is the T_DONOR table:

### [image: T_DONOR]

T_RECIPIENT_1:
[image]

---

T_RECIPIENT_2: 
[image]

---

This is what I want the final table to look like with more recipients and their information to the right.

[image]

---

T_RECIPIENT_3 and T_RECIPIENT_4 are the same as T_RECIPIENT_1 and T_RECIPIENT_2 except that they have different RECIPIENT ID and different names. I want to combine all 5 of these tables so on one line I can have the DONOR_CONTACT_ID which his information, and then all of the Recipient's information.

The problem is that when I try to run a query, it does not work because not all of the Donors have all of the recipient fields filled, so the query will run and give a blank table. Some instances I have a Donor with 4 Recipients and other times I have a Donor with only 1 Recipient so this causes a problem. I've tried running queries where I connect them with the DONOR_CONTACT_ID but this will only work if all of the RECIPIENT fields are filled. Any suggestions on what to do? Is there a way I could manipulate this in VBA? I only know some VBA, I'm not an expert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I think you want all rows from `T_DONOR`.  And then you want to pull in information from the recipient tables when they include `DONOR_CONTACT_ID` matches.  If that is correct, `LEFT JOIN T_DONOR` to the other tables.

Start with a simpler set of fields; you can add in the "name" fields after you get the joins set to correctly return the rest of the data you need.

```sql
SELECT
    d.DONOR_CONTACT_ID,
    r1.RECIPIENT_1,
    r2.RECIPIENT_1
FROM
    (T_DONOR AS d
    LEFT JOIN T_RECIPIENT_1 AS r1
    ON d.ORDER_NUMBER = r1.ORDER_NUMBER)
    LEFT JOIN T_RECIPIENT_2 AS r2
    ON d.ORDER_NUMBER = r2.ORDER_NUMBER;
```

Notice the parentheses in the `FROM` clause.  The db engine requires them for any query which includes more than one join.  If possible, set up your joins in Design View of the query designer.  The query designer knows how to add parentheses to keep the db engine happy.

Here is a version without aliased table names in case it's easier to understand and set up in the query designer ...

```sql
SELECT
    T_DONOR.DONOR_CONTACT_ID,
    T_RECIPIENT_1.RECIPIENT_1,
    T_RECIPIENT_2.RECIPIENT_1
FROM
    (T_DONOR
    LEFT JOIN T_RECIPIENT_1
    ON T_DONOR.ORDER_NUMBER = T_RECIPIENT_1.ORDER_NUMBER)
    LEFT JOIN T_RECIPIENT_2
    ON T_DONOR.ORDER_NUMBER = T_RECIPIENT_2.ORDER_NUMBER;
```

Comment: I'm not really familiar with SQL, so I tried putting this in my code but I got really confused and didn't know what to do. What exactly is this doing, and what are d, r1, and r2? Thanks again for answering my question HansUp! You always come to the rescue haha.

Comment: d, r1, and r2 are aliases for the table names.  I find them more convenient than the full table names.  But you don't have to use them if they confuse you.  Can you use the query designer to set up your joins?

Comment: Yes I can use the query designer. Is that an option instead of writing the SQL you suggested?

Comment: Definitely!  Concentrate on the joins at first and use my SQL as a model to guide you --- yours will look similar at least.  I added a version of the query without table aliases to make it easier for you in the query designer.  In the designer, when you create the join lines between tables, right-click each line to choose the "join properties" ... should be something like *"Include ALL records from 'T_DONOR' and only those records from 'T_RECIPIENT_1' where the joined fields are equal"*.

Comment: In the query designer switch from "Design View" to "SQL View".  There you will see the SQL the designer created for you, and I hope it will at least resemble the SQL from my answer.  But don't *add* my SQL --- create your own with the query designer.

Comment: Thank you that worked!! I had the join lines before but I just edited them to what you said and they worked. Thank you again HansUp! You're quite the access expert.

Comment: So there are a max of 4 recipient fields, so if a donor has more than 4 recipients, I would make a new record in the table with the same Donor Id and the other recipients. The join worked when I had only 4 recipients, but when I just added a 5th recipient, it created a new record with that Donor Id, and then the final table that is created from the 5 table join did not work. Any thoughts on why this would happen?

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT T_DONOR.ORDER_NUMBER, T_DONOR.DONOR_CONTACT_ID, T_DONOR.FIRST_NAME, T_DONOR.LAST_NAME, T_RECIPIENT_1.RECIPIENT_1, T_RECIPIENT_1.FIRST_NAME, T_RECIPIENT_1.LASTNAME 
        FROM T_DONOR 
        JOIN T_RECIPIENT_1 
        ON T_DONOR.DONOR_CONTACT_ID = T_RECIPIENT_1.DONOR_CONTACT_ID
```

This shows you how to JOIN the first recipient table, you should be able to follow the same structure for the other three...